# WebClient downloads the source page only once Help please C#

Tags: c#

I want to download Html Source Code And extract content from it, but the webclient only downloads once,
The second time it doesnt work until I exit the program and restart it again.

This is the download function and I called it in a button:

```
public static async Task DownF(string[] Urls)
        {

            WebClient KeyClient = new WebClient();




            try
            {
                await Task.Run(() =>
                {

                    const string pattern = "<span.*?>(.*?)<\\/span>";


                    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                    {
                        while (KeyClient.IsBusy)
                        {
                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        }

                        string page = KeyClient.DownloadString(Urls[i]);

                        MatchCollection matchs = Regex.Matches(page, pattern);
                        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

                        if (matchs.Count > 0)
                        {
                            StreamWriter wrt = new StreamWriter(path + "\\results.txt");


                            int KeyWordCounter = 0;
                            foreach (Match m in matchs)
                            {
                                KeyWordCounter += 1;

                                wrt.WriteLine(KeyWordCounter + "-" + m.Groups[1].Value);

                            }
                            wrt.Close();
                        }

                    }

                    MessageBox.Show("finich!");
                });
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);

            }
```

//*********call function in button

```
string site1 = "www.site1.com";
                string site2 = "www.site2.com";
                string site3 = "www.site3.com";

                string [] Urls = new string[3];
                Urls[0] = site1;
                Urls[1] = site2;
                Urls[2] = site3;
                 DownF(Urls);
```

Comment: Replace `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)` by `Task.Delay()`

Comment: Erro: no overloaded for method Delay takes 0 argument

Comment: yes, you need to pass the 1000

Comment: the same problem Task.Delay() not working

Comment: Task.Delay(System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1000)); NOT WORKING the same problem

Comment: In what **specific** way is it not working?

Comment: Create a new `WebClient` on each loop iteration. Alternatively, move the webclient `Close` **outside** of the loop.

Comment: Give me an exemple

Comment: Hi,
how Find text between two special html tags using html agility, i am trying to extract all texts between and in a webpage using html agility c#, but i didn't know what the xpath:
<span class="a-title-heade a-step-one a-text-normal" dir="auto">
Science is a systematic enterprise that builds and organizes knowledge in the form of testable explanations and predictions about the universe
</span>

Answer (score 0):

I agree with D.Foley. You can install **Selenium.WebDriver** through NuGet and it will give you all the functions to use you need. It's a pretty cool package that allows you to extract data via multiple ways from a browser. It has something like getByXPath(), getByCssSelector(), etc. Also, it will give you a fast and easy opportunity to navigate around the website very easily.

**Update**:

If we assume that the element you are trying to get will be at the same spot every time you reload the web page you can open that web page in Chrome browser and right-click on an element you need to get XPATH for and then follow the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Hi,
how Find text between two special html tags using html agility, i am trying to extract all texts between and in a webpage using html agility c#, but i didn't know what the xpath:
<span class="a-title-heade a-step-one a-text-normal" dir="auto">
Science is a systematic enterprise that builds and organizes knowledge in the form of testable explanations and predictions about the universe
</span>

Comment: Hi, if I understood you correctly then you can look at the updated answer. You can right-click on any element on a webpage and then go to **Inspect**. Then right-click again and go to **Copy** and get whatever you need in terms of paths.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing async and sync calls, potentially causing deadlocks. You're also not disposing of the StreamWriter, which could be an issue.

Try the following:

```cs
WebClient KeyClient = new WebClient();

try
{

    const string pattern = "<span.*?>(.*?)<\\/span>";

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        string page = await KeyClient.DownloadStringAsync(Urls[i]);

        MatchCollection matchs = Regex.Matches(page, pattern);
        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

        if (matchs.Count > 0)
        {
            using (StreamWriter wrt = new StreamWriter(path + "\\results.txt"))
            {
                int KeyWordCounter = 0;
                foreach (Match m in matchs)
                {
                    KeyWordCounter += 1;

                    await wrt.WriteLineAsync(KeyWordCounter + "-" + m.Groups[1].Value);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    MessageBox.Show("finich!");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
}
```

Comment: Hi,
how Find text between two special html tags using html agility, i am trying to extract all texts between and in a webpage using html agility c#, but i didn't know what the xpath:
<span class="a-title-heade a-step-one a-text-normal" dir="auto">
Science is a systematic enterprise that builds and organizes knowledge in the form of testable explanations and predictions about the universe
</span>

Comment: Can you tell me how to write the XPATH  for this html tags?